# DRY principle and JS object

Tags: javascript

```
const LISTENING_TASKS = {
    _7B2CDA: {number: "7B2CDA",
          type: TASKS_TYPES.written_1,},
    _DGA445: {number: "DGA445",
          type: TASKS_TYPES.written_2,},
}
```

The problem here is that DRY principle is violated. Namely: _7B2CDA equals "7B2CDA".

I need this number both to find the JS object and to use further. But I don't want to repeat myself.

Comment: What *should be* the shape of the data being modeled?  Intuitively, to me, `LISTENING_TASKS` sounds like it should be an array.  But I can't speak to any changes that might require throughout the rest of the code.

Comment: @David, I have eidited my question.  Anyway, it is a collection. A map of number - task type.

Comment: Is there a particular reason this isn't an array then?  If you change this structure to an array, what fails?

Comment: DRY principle is applicable for code, not for data structures. I don't see why it should be problem to index by one of fields _and_ have that same field inside data

Comment: Please explain why dropping one of both would lead to problems. Without context of the problem you try to solve it seems impossible to answer this.

Comment: @Justinas, DRY is a principle. This code is error prone. The most horrible logical mistake may appear if just one symbol is confused.

Comment: @Kifsif So if your usage allows to remove `name` field, then remove it. If context allows to work with plain array, then don't index by name field.

Comment: @trincot, _7B2CDA is a key. Impossible to drop - Ineed it to find the object. "7B2CDA" is just necessary because I was unable to use the number. For example, if I iterate over objects, I want to use the number. But I failed to extract it from the key.

Comment: @Justinas, you mean "number"? I would be happy. But how can I show numbers in case of an iteration over a collection of such objects? I failed and had to insert "number" and its value, that is repeat myself.

Comment: @Kifsif By showing iteration index?

Comment: @Justinas, but I need the number.

Comment: @Kifsif: So far the only reasons given for why this "can't be an array" are (1) *"_7B2CDA is a key. Impossible to drop"* and (2) *"I failed and had to insert "number" and its value"*.  It's not really clear what you're asking us.  With no context of any code which uses this structure, you're asking us to change this structure without making any changes to this structure.  Aside from a guess below, which is as good as any other guess, what exactly are you looking for here?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to make a value in an object a reference to a property on another object.

This is the sort of thing that calls for a function.

```js
const TASKS_TYPES = {
  written_1: 1,
  written_2: 2,
}

const LISTENING_TASKS = {};

const addTask = (number, data) => {
  LISTENING_TASKS[`_${number}`] = {
    number,
    ...data
  };
}

addTask("7B2CDA", {
  type: TASKS_TYPES.written_1
});
addTask("DGA445", {
  type: TASKS_TYPES.written_2
});

console.log(LISTENING_TASKS);
```

Comment: Let us have an object LISTENING_TASKS["7B2CDA"]. Just an arbitrary object. Then if is transferred to another function or something. Anyway, the number is inside it. How to show the number?